# Загадочный пропуск кадров в java-приложении под linux-системой

Tags: java, linux, linux-mint

Заранее оговорюсь, что я с джавой не знаком и меня интересует этот вопрос чисто как пользователя линукс-системы, но все ответы, связанные с техническими деталями, всё равно приветствуются.

В общем, мой друг написал простую змейку под виндой на джаве, дал мне её протестировать и я заметил, что она у меня тормозит (linux mint cinnamon). Под windows у него всё работает стабильно. Тогда мы начали пробовать разные варианты и нашли проблему: когда окно перерисовывает своё содержимое, оно пропускает кадры если курсор находится не в его пределах! Речь идёт о софтверном рендеринге, с opengl скорее всего такой проблемы нет.

Я попросил его сделать для примера простейшие часы с милисекундами. Вот короткое [видео](https://youtu.be/n_gosETh67w) того, как это выглядит. Вот [исходник часов](http://pastebin.com/aA4rAdtS). Вот сами [часы](https://yadi.sk/d/d22tKZCV33YqtD).

Скажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема? Почему java, которая изначально задумывалась как кросплатформенная виртуальная машина, так себя ведёт? Очень похоже на то, что система считает что окно потеряло фокус когда над ним нет курсора, в windows тоже имеется подобная оптимизация, но ведь в данном случае окно фокус не теряет! Зачем ему этот курсор?

Comment: попробуйте после отрисовки добавить вызов `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();`

Comment: @zRrr спасибо, помогло! Объясните пожалуйста в форме ответа, каким образом это решает проблему?

Comment: понятия не имею. скорее всего по дороге кто-то (x11, драйвер видеокарты, возможно java2d) оптимизирует процесс, откладывая отрисовку. `sync()` заставляет отобразить актуальное состояние. Надеюсь, кто-то объяснит, это связано с положением курсора.